# Function in angular service returning data late?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a service that contains a function to set and return default user preferences.  I am experiencing a strange problem that I believe has to do with the async nature of returning the data. I will show you the calls and then explain the problem.

The service is defined as follows:

```
var StateService = angular.module('StateService', [])
.service('HoldState', function ($http, $q) {
```

In the app.js I have the following injection:

```
var JBenchApp = angular.module('JBenchApp', [
    'ngRoute',
    'StateService'
]);
```

In the controller I also have the following injection:

```
JBenchApp.controller('CaseListCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', 'HoldState', 
  function ($scope, $http, HoldState) {
```

The following is the function I am calling:

```
this.getUserDefaults = function (UserID) {
        var userDefaults = [], deferred = $q.defer();
        $http.get('http://10.34.34.46/BenchViewServices/api/UserPreference/Default/' + UserID)
            .then(function (response) {
                userDefaults = response;
                //var status = getStatus();
                var status = localStorage.getItem('Status');

                // If the status is 0 then we have not yet navigated anywhere so we will need to set the path values to be
                // the same as the default. We do nothing if status is not 0 because it means we already have path values set
                if (status == 0 || status == null) {
                    /**setTypeOfLaw(response.LitigationCode);
                    setCourthouse(response.LocID);
                    setDepartment(response.CourtRoom);**/
                    localStorage.setItem('LawType', response.LitigationCode);
                    localStorage.setItem('Building', response.LocID);
                    localStorage.setItem('Dept', response.CourtRoom);
                    localStorage.setItem('Status', 1);
                }
                alert("value: " + userDefaults.PreferenceID);
                deferred.resolve(response);
            }, function (response) {
                console.log(response.status + " -- " + response.data + " -- " + response.statusText);
            });


        return deferred.promise;
    };
```

The following is the code where I am seeing the strange issue:

```
$scope.fillDefaults = function () {
          HoldState.getUserDefaults('dpeng').then(function (data) {
              $scope.userDefaults = data;
              //$scope.$apply();
          });


      }

$scope.fillDefaults();
```

The issue that I am seeing is that the function is called and entered. Processing then returns to the line $scope.userDefaults, but it winds up undefined. It seems that the code goes to through the $scope.fillDefaults function before the data is returned. I suspect this because the alert errors saying that it cannot find property PreferenceID of undefined. I have checked the API call through PostMan and it works just fine. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: What field is undefined exactly? If you are speaking about the value you will have in the ```alert``` popup, yes, that code will be executed first. You might want to move your alert into the callback of ```getUserDefault```

Comment: Even putting it into the callback of getUserDefault I still get an undefined on that value in the alert yet I know it is in the data. This is how the data looks in postman:

'{
  "PreferenceID": 16,
  "UserID": "dpeng",
  "UserName": "Derek Peng",
  "LitigationCode": "PR",
  "LitigationType": "Probate",
  "LocID": "LA ",
  "LocName": "Stanley Mosk Courthouse",
  "CourtRoom": "5",
  "IsDefault": true
}'

Comment: That is the beauty of promises. It is even happening in your current scenario. The ```then``` method is doing exactly that, waiting until the deferred promise returned by ```getUserDefaults``` is resolved before calling the callback. You can then keep returning promises and chain with ```then```. I encourage you to read about the promise library used by Angular (Or in general even): https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q

Comment: Have you tried to debug in that function to see what you have in ```data```?

Comment: yes, the data is correct. As for the beauty of promises, how exactly is it helping me if I cannot ever seem to see the data? So you are saying that the answer to my other question is that I should chain the promises together with then statements and then have the first function get called and when the promise returns call the second function and so on? Thanks, I will read that link you provided.

Comment: No, even in that state, you should see your date in the alert if you moved it. Can you please update your question with the new code? Thanks

Comment: I have updated the code above accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`fillDefaults` is a red herring; the problem is in `getUserDefaults`: you're assigning `http.get`'s full response object to `userDefaults`, instead of the response data.

```
$http.get('http://10.34.34.46/BenchViewServices/api/UserPreference/Default/' + UserID)
            .then(function (response) {
                userDefaults = response;
```

should be

```
$http.get('http://10.34.34.46/BenchViewServices/api/UserPreference/Default/' + UserID)
        .then(function (response) {
            userDefaults = response.data;
```

Comment: Easy mistake to make, I catch myself doing that one all the time